# RDS file to feather: Error: `x` must be a data frame

Tags: r, feather

I've imported an `*.rds` file via `data = readRDS("file.rds")`.

[image]

[image]

Now I am trying to save the matrices as `*.feather` files. I tried `write_feather("test.feather", data[1986])` which returns `Error:` x `must be a data frame`. However, `write_feather("test.feather", as.data.frame(data[1986]))` and `write_feather("test.feather", as.data.frame(as.matrix(data[1986])))` return the same error.

How can I save the data set's subsets as `*.feather` files?

Comment: Well, `x` *is a list*. If you want to write out individual items in that list, you need to subset your list — using `[[`, not `[`: `x[[1986L]]` will work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and apologies ... first day at work :D `data[[1986]]` and `data[[1986L]]` both yield `Error in data[[1986]] : subscript out of bounds`.

Comment: @Stücke are you able to provide a subset of your data?

Comment: @Stücke Right, I missed that: your list only has 28 elements. Use a smaller index, or, if these numbers are the *names* of the list, use quotes around them: `x[[1L]]` should work, as should `x[['1986']]`. And you might still require `as.data.frame` around that, depending on what the data type of the list elements is (I don’t know the `dgCMatrix` class, but it doesn’t look like it can be implicitly treated as a data.frame).

Comment: Yes, that works `data[["1986"]]`! Great, thank you. You want to post that as an answer?